# Write/Read file in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-os

So I got a new GeeksPhone Peak, and started making apps in HTML5, CSS, JavaScript.. It is great, I love it, but now I'm trying to make a timetable app and I have to save data, when I fill my timetable (just text) somehow, and reload it when the app is loaded.

I started searching and found localStorage, IndexDB, backbone.local-storage but couldn't really find great tutorials on them. Or is there a special API for that case? Can someone help me on which one to use, or how to write to file, save it, read it, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

FirefoxOS provides multiple mechanisms for supporting persistence in your application. While considering the choice between local Storage and Indexed DB, your decision will rest on how important the following points are for your application:

- How easy the API is use [Local Storage is easier. Simple key-value pairs]
- Synchronous v/s Asynchronous API [Local Storage is synchronous. IndexedDB has both modes]
- Transaction Support [Indexed DB has it]
- How easy it is to do Search [Since local storage is just key-value pairs, it is difficult to do searches especially if your values contain complex structures]

A good article that provides comparison is [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/).

In case, you want to take a look at how to use the localStorage, IndexedDB APIs on FirefoxOS, I have written tutorials on the same: [localStorage](http://rominirani.com/2013/08/01/firefox-os-tutorial-episode-6-enabling-storage/) & [IndexedDB](http://rominirani.com/2013/08/15/firefox-os-tutorial-episode-7-storage-using-indexeddb/) & [Device Storage](http://rominirani.com/2013/08/16/firefox-os-tutorial-episode-9-device-storage/).